# Getting "Class "X" does not have a main method." error, even though it has a main method

Tags: java

i am receiving a "Class "X" does not have a main method." error, even though I believe that there is one in my code, and it was running minutes before. i even undid a lot of the work i did, back to a point when it ran, and it gave me the same error. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] arrayInput,int n) throws  FileNotFoundException{
        int counter=0;
        //HashMap<String, Integer> playerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Garth Vader\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NBA.txt"));
        //arrayInput will be the input array of the objects of NBAPlayer.java
        /*String[] newPlayerNameArray = new String[arrayInput.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arrayInput.length;i++){
            newPlayerNameArray[i]=arrayInput[i].getLastName()+","+arrayInput[i].getFirstName();
        }*/
        while(file.hasNext()){
            if(counter<1){
                counter++;
                file.nextLine();
            }
            else{String s = file.nextLine().trim();
            String[] a =s.split("\\s+");
            String playerName=a[0];
            double totalMins =Double.parseDouble(a[4]);
            System.out.println(a[19]);
            //double versatilityMean=Math.pow((), 1.0/5);

            //System.out.println(totalMins);
            //System.out.println(playerName);
            //playerMap.put(playerName, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `main` method **must** have exactly *one* argument: a String array:  `String[]` Yours doesn't. You need to remove the `int n` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method doesn't match the required signature of

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

You have an extra `int n` parameter. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a main method that can be used as entry point for an application.

The only arguments you are allowed to pass is an array of Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] a){
```

--> this is a valid entry point. Change the signature, like you did:

```
public static void main(String[] a, int n){
```

--> this is not a valid entry point.